# How to forbid Kubuntu 13.04 Task Manager to group similar instances of an opened program?

Tags: kubuntu, taskbar

Kubuntu Task Manager (taskbar at the bottom of the desktop) groups similar instances of a program. How forbid it? I want similar instances follow one another.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on task manager pane, go to `Task manager settings` and see under `Grouping and Sorting`.